# How to test a void method and assert its side affect in the file system

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

I have a void method that checks if a given path exists and if not creates it, it is contained in a FileServices class with an IFileServices corresponding interface

```
public interface IFileServices{
   void CreateFolder(string path);
}

public class FileServices : IFileServices{

   private readonly IDirectory _directory;

   public FileServices(IDirectory directory){
       _directory = directory;
   }
   
   public void CreateFolder(string path){
      if(!_directory.Exists(path))
        _directory.CreateDirectory(path)
   }
}
```

I'm trying to test with Nunit and Moq where the passed path doesn't exist and then it is created

```
[Test]
public void TestDirectoryDontExistAndCreated()
{
    var mockedDir = new Mock<IDirectory>();
    
    mockedDir.Setup(s => s.Exists(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(false);
    mockedDir.Setup(s => s.CreateDirectory(It.IsAny<string>())).Callback((string path) => { Directory.CreateDirectory(path); });

    var service = new FileServices(mockedDir);
    service.CreateFolder("C:\\temp:\\testDir");
    Assert.IsTrue(Directory.Exists("C:\\temp:\\testDir"));
}
```

my issues/questions are

1. Assert is failing
2. is there a better way to do this without using Directory class ?
3. I thought about adding a new setup for s.Exists after the invocation of service.CreateFolder so it would return true for the passed value, would this be considered a good practice ? something like:

```
mockedDir.Setup(s => s.Exists("C:\\temp:\\testDir")).Returns(true);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of creating the folder using `Directory` (and depending on it), you can validate if mock methods of `IDirectory` were invoked or not. If those are invoked then you would be covering the `CreateFolder` of `FileServices`. Use `Verify` of moq to validate the invocation of methods.

```
[Test]
public void TestDirectoryDontExistAndCreated()
{
    var mockedDir = new Mock<IDirectory>();
    
    mockedDir.Setup(s => s.Exists(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(false);
    mockedDir.Setup(s => s.CreateDirectory(It.IsAny<string>()));

    var service = new FileServices(mockedDir);
    
    // Asserts
    mockedDir.Verify(mock => mock.Exists(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once());
    mockedDir.Verify(mock => mock.CreateDirectory(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once());
}
```

With above approach, now you can also validate the scenario when directory exist (by validating the 0 invocation of `CreateDirectory` method).